# Proving two equal probability functions

Tags: probability, exponential-function, logistic-regression

How do I prove that these probability functions are equal?

$$ P = \frac{e^{(a+bx)}}{1+e^{(a+bx)}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(a+bx)}}
$$

Comment: Hint: Divide numerator and denominator by ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?
\begin{align*}
P = \frac{e^{(a+bx)}}{1+e^{(a+bx)}} = \frac{e^{(a+bx)}}{e^{(a+bx)}(\frac{1}{e^{(a+bx)}}+1)} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(a+bx)}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoDomingues & @Ak!